# Content Security Policy is set, but not detected

Tags: django, content-security-policy

I have `django-csp` version `3.7` (https://pypi.org/project/django-csp/).

It is added to the middleware section:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'csp.middleware.CSPMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

And here's my settings:

```
CSP_DEFAULT_SRC = ["'none'"]
CSP_IMG_SRC = ["'self'"]
CSP_STYLE_SRC = ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'"]
CSP_STYLE_SRC_ELEM = ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'", "https://fonts.googleapis.com"]
CSP_SCRIPT_SRC_ELEM = ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'"]
CSP_FONT_SRC = ["'self'", "data:", "https://fonts.googleapis.com", "https://fonts.gstatic.com"]
```

I know that the above settings work because first I had lots of errors in the browser console and then all gone and the site works correctly.

However, two sites checking the host headers ([this one](https://securityheaders.com/) and [this one](https://www.serpworx.com/check-security-headers/)) both report that my site is missing Content Security Policy. What I'm missing here?

Comment: Do you see them in your response headers?